# Volley Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path

Tags: java, android, gson, android-volley

Hello i am getting the below error, getting error says expected array but was object 
i have also provide the url please guide...not familiar with json parsing just started unable to understand the error if possible please explain with the solution.

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

ServerUrl
https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest

**Request**

```
 StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("Code",response);
                GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                UnofficialSummary[] data =    gson.fromJson(response,UnofficialSummary[].class);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new cronatracker(RSSFeedActivity.this,data));
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(request);
```

Unofficialsummary.class

```
public class UnofficialSummary {

    @SerializedName("source")
    @Expose
    private String source;
    @SerializedName("total")
    @Expose
    private Integer total;
    @SerializedName("recovered")
    @Expose
    private Integer recovered;
    @SerializedName("deaths")
    @Expose
    private Integer deaths;
    @SerializedName("active")
    @Expose
    private Integer active;

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public Integer getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(Integer total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public Integer getRecovered() {
        return recovered;
    }

    public void setRecovered(Integer recovered) {
        this.recovered = recovered;
    }

    public Integer getDeaths() {
        return deaths;
    }

    public void setDeaths(Integer deaths) {
        this.deaths = deaths;
    }

    public Integer getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Integer active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

}
```

Comment: Response data is an object not an array. And you should create whole objects.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir can you help me to fix this with exact code

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 0):

ResponseData.class

```
public class ResponseData {

@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private Boolean success;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private Data data;
@SerializedName("lastRefreshed")
@Expose
private String lastRefreshed;
@SerializedName("lastOriginUpdate")
@Expose
private String lastOriginUpdate;

/* Getters and setters */

}
```

Data.class

```
public class Data {

@SerializedName("summary")
@Expose
private Summary summary;
@SerializedName("unofficial-summary")
@Expose
private List<UnofficialSummary> unofficialSummary = null;
@SerializedName("regional")
@Expose
private List<Regional> regional = null;

/* Getters and setters */

}
```

Regional.class

```
public class Regional {

@SerializedName("confirmedCasesIndian")
@Expose
private Integer confirmedCasesIndian;
@SerializedName("confirmedCasesForeign")
@Expose
private Integer confirmedCasesForeign;
@SerializedName("discharged")
@Expose
private Integer discharged;
@SerializedName("deaths")
@Expose
private Integer deaths;
@SerializedName("loc")
@Expose
private String loc;
@SerializedName("totalConfirmed")
@Expose
private Integer totalConfirmed;

/* Getters and setters */

}
```

Summary.class

```
public class Summary {

@SerializedName("total")
@Expose
private Integer total;
@SerializedName("confirmedCasesIndian")
@Expose
private Integer confirmedCasesIndian;
@SerializedName("confirmedCasesForeign")
@Expose
private Integer confirmedCasesForeign;
@SerializedName("discharged")
@Expose
private Integer discharged;
@SerializedName("deaths")
@Expose
private Integer deaths;
@SerializedName("confirmedButLocationUnidentified")
@Expose
private Integer confirmedButLocationUnidentified;

/* Getters and setters */

}
```

UnofficialSummary.class

```
public class UnofficialSummary {

@SerializedName("source")
@Expose
private String source;
@SerializedName("total")
@Expose
private Integer total;
@SerializedName("recovered")
@Expose
private Integer recovered;
@SerializedName("deaths")
@Expose
private Integer deaths;
@SerializedName("active")
@Expose
private Integer active;

/* Getters and setters */

}
```

onResponse method

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
       Log.d("Code",response);
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       ResponseData data = gson.fromJson(response,ResponseData.class);
       if(data.getSuccess()){
          recyclerView.setAdapter(new cronatracker(RSSFeedActivity.this,data.getData().getUnofficialSummary()));
       }
}
```